# Вывести получившийся массив в Listview

Tags: java, javafx

Имеется следующий код. Необходимо получившейся массив вставить в Linked list...=(

```
@FXML
public void okBtnAction() {
    String massGet = elemNumbers.getText();
    i = Integer.parseInt(massGet);
    ArrayList massive = new ArrayList();
    //Заполняем массив случайными числами
    for (int x = 0; x < i; x++) {
        massive.add(x, (int) (Math.random() * 100));
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
linkedList.addAll(massive);
```

И это кстати не массив, а коллекция.

А вы случайно не ошиблись? В тайтле `ListView`, в вопросе `LinkedList`. На всякий пожарный

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, massive.toArray(new String[0]));
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: кстати, почему он не редактируемый? вообще стоит true editable..не получилось у меня сделать его редактируемым...=(

Comment: Кого сделать редактируемым? Можно поподробнее?

Comment: добавил в топик изображение. ячейки в листе не редактируемые.